# adding class to list element after page redirection using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I will keep my question short for the sake of brevity. I have a page (lets say page 1) on which I have 2 links attached to two different anchor tag and on clicking those anchor tag, I am redirecting user to page 2. However I would like to highlight (add class 'active') on two different list element on page 2, which depends whether the user have clicked anchor 1 or 2 from the previous page. As of now the first li tag is highlight with class active.

This is my HTML markup on page 1 where I have anchor tags

```
<div class="landing-thumb">
    <div class="view view-first">
        <div class="mask">
            <a id="link1" class="info">Click here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="landing-thumb">
    <div class="view view-first">
        <div class="mask">
            <a id="link2" class="info">Click here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS for on click event

```
$('#link1').on('click', function () {
    window.location = "/page2";
});
$('#link2').on('click', function () {
    window.location = "/page2";
});
```

On page 2, I have a list which is generated dynamically (by default the first element in list has a class 'active') (only the span id is different for every list element). Here is the rough HTML mark up

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
            <span id="spanLink1">List 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span id="spanLink2">List 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span id="spanLink3">List 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span id="spanLink4">List 4</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now what I am trying to achieve over here if the user click on link1 from page 1, he/she will be redirected to page 2 with li class active which has span id="spanLink3" and on clicking link2 from page 1 li class active which has`span id="spanLink4"`

Comment: have you tried using the browsers localStorage?

Comment: why would I need localStorage or cookies for this prob? I am not trying to save the URL's or anything similar to that.

Comment: You are trying to save information over a reload of a page aren't you?

Comment: I think you cannot (unless using server side) save information (even a state/class of an element) over a reload without saving this info somewhere either in the browser storage (cookies/local) or on the server..

Comment: No. I am just trying to make the respective list element active after clicking the anchor link from page 1, instead of showing the default first link with class active on page 2. On page 2 reload I dont care if the active class go back to the the default first active list element. So saving info in local/cookies is out of question

Comment: so you're saying, when you click on an anchor link, you want the page to reload with the respective 'active' li...? basically, when you click a link, you are going from page1 to page2.. correct? in other words, you are reloading or loading a page.. correct? or is this just js operations on the same page with no reloading?

Comment: yes. However I would use the term redirect (similar to href tag) instead of calling it reload. Also there are 2 different pages we are talking about in the question posted.

Comment: Yes, redirect is a better term for it.. in any case, if you are redirecting, and the new page 'view' is conditional to something that happened in the page before.. that means, you need to pass information like I said..

Comment: yeah. I am simple going from page 1 to page 2 and If user click on anchor id link1 (on page 1). I am calling another page (page 2) with the third li active on page 2. Note: I am trying to make the list active using span id.

Comment: on page2, how do you know which span id should become active?

Comment: I am already aware of the span id I need to make active. so for e.g in  my question if I click on link 1 (page 1). I will make the third list (li) active which has span id spanLink3 (on page 2)

Comment: Yes, you are aware on page1 that you clicked on link1, but on page2 how are you aware that spanLink3 should be active?

Comment: that's why I asked the question. How do I make list active which has span id=spanLink3 on page 2.

Comment: Basically what I'm getting at is that you need page2 to know 'somehow' what you clicked on, you can use a hashtag as suggested in the answer below.. or use some kind of storage

Answer (score 2):

Add some hash tag into your url

```
$('#link1').on('click', function () {
    window.location = "/page2#link1";
});
$('#link2').on('click', function () {
    window.location = "/page2#link2";
});
```

And on that page get this hash tag 
`window.location.hash` or use php code also and add class accordint to it

Comment: This will not do any good to my problem. Also, my web app is not PHP based.

Comment: my friend i just mension javascript code also here use window.location.hash on page load and enjoy
this will return you the hash tag data

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this actually looks like a good solution.. use the hashtag between pages.. this is not php.. anyways I think it should be - window.location.href

Comment: ofcourse I know this is not PHP :) I was just replying to the answer when Jain mentioned about using PHP code. Well, I dont have any id on the list (on page 2). The only thing which is distinct is the span id enclosed under li tag

Comment: yes ofcourse you can use window.location.href.split('#').pop() to get data after hash tag then search id into your page then add class
$('#spanid').addClass('whatever');

Comment: use for example window.location.href = "/page2.html#spanLink1"; then with the split pop method @Jain referred to, store it in a 'var activespan' or something, and then $(activespan).parents('li:first').addClass('active')